# Why is this true? $(\exists x, Px \to r) \iff (\forall x, Px) \to r$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I can totally understand the forward direction: if there is an $x$ such that $Px$ implies $r$, then clearly having $Px$ true for all $x$ will imply $r$. But the other direction doesn't make any sense to me.

If I give a more natural example, assume that "If it rains every day this week, then the pot will be full of water". Here, $r$ is "the pot is full of water", $x$ ranges over the days of this week, and $Px$ denotes that it rains on a particular day. The statement in the title would suggest that there is a single day of the week such that if it rains on that day, then the pot will be full, and that's just not true.

So what am I missing? Because apparently the statement in the title is true, it can be proven, so where does my understanding break down?

Comment: Looks like a variation of the Drinkers Paradox.  And one explanation I like is briefly: the problem is trying to interpret implication as a "causation" relation, rather than just a useful binary operation on true/false values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$(\forall x, Px) \to r\implies(\exists x, Px \to r) $$

Clearer: $$(\forall x\, Px) \to R\implies\exists x\, (Px \to R) $$

> assume that
>
> - if it rains every day this week, then the pot ***will be*** full
>
> then
>
> - there is a single day this week such that if it rains on that
>   day, then the pot ***will be*** full

Since $R$ is not a function of $x$ (this point is crucial for the title's equivalence to hold), this is less ambiguous:

assumption (A)

- if it rains every day this week, then the pot will be full *next week*

consequence (C)

- there is some day this week such that if it rains on that day, then the pot will be full *next week*

(A) says: **either the pot will be full next week or some day this week isn't rainy.** In particular: **on some day this week, (either the pot will be full next week or some day this week isn't rainy).**  Thus: **on some day this week, either the pot will be full next week or that day isn't rainy.** This is exactly what (C) says.

Therefore, (C) is a consequence of (A).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Daniel Schepler for the push in the right direction. This is indeed the [Drinker Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox), which comes from looking at implication as a causal relationship, instead of as just a way of categorising patterns in pairs of boolean values.

Answer (score 3):

One way of seeing that $(\exists x, Px \to r)$ and $(\forall x, Px) \to r$ are equivalent is to show that their negations are equivalent. The negation of $(\exists x, Px \to r)$ is equivalent to $\forall x, \lnot (Px \to r)$ which is itself equivalent to $\forall x, (Px \land \lnot r)$; while the negation of $(\forall x, Px) \to r$ is equivalent to $(\forall x, Px) \land \lnot r$. These two statements are more easily seen to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(\forall x, Px)\to r$

Assume $\neg(\exists x, Px\to r)$, that is: no $a$ will satisfy $Pa\to r$.

Now if every $a$ satisfied $Pa$ , then $r$ holds, so there are $a$ which satisfy $Pa\to r$ (a contradiction).  And if some $a$ does not satisfy $Pa$, then that satisfies $Pa\to r$, (also a contradiction).

Either way, the assumption is contradicted.